# Detect power change event / UPS state

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

I want to detect when the system is on `UPS` or just power state changes.

**Something like this:**

[image]

I tried to detect it using `GetSystemPowerStatus` function:

**Code:**

```
    SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS powerStatus;
    bool powerStatusRes = GetSystemPowerStatus(&powerStatus);

    switch (powerStatus.ACLineStatus) {
        case 0:
            std::cout << "Offline" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 1:
            std::cout << "Online" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 255:
            std::cout << "Unknown status" << std::endl;
        default:
            std::cout << "Failed to detect the status" << std::endl;
    }

    switch (powerStatus.BatteryFlag) {
        case 1:
            std::cout << "High — the battery capacity is at more than 66 percent" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            std::cout << "Low — the battery capacity is at less than 33 percent" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            std::cout << "Critical — the battery capacity is at less than five percent" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 8:
            std::cout << "Charging" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 128:
            std::cout << "No system battery" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 255:
            std::cout << "Unknown status—unable to read the battery flag information" << std::endl;
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Failed to detect the battery flag" << std::endl;
    }
```

But it returns `powerStatus.ACLineStatus` for `UPS` or `AC` as `Online` and for `powerStatus.BatteryFlag` - `No system battery`.

Also I have tried to detect the `UPS` using `GetPwrCapabilities` function:

**Code:**

```
SYSTEM_POWER_CAPABILITIES SysPowerCapabilities = {0};

if (!GetPwrCapabilities(&SysPowerCapabilities)){
    std::cout << "Failed to get System Power information!" << std::endl;
}

if (SysPowerCapabilities.UpsPresent) {
    std::cout << "UPS found" << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "UPS not found" << std::endl;
}
```

It returns - `UPS not found` (driver is not available for this `UPS` model).

Now I'm trying to detect power changes by using the `Qt nativeEvent` function:

```
bool Test::nativeEvent(const QByteArray &eventType, void *message, long *result)
{
    Q_UNUSED(result);
    Q_UNUSED(eventType);
    MSG *msg = static_cast<MSG*>(message);

    if (msg->message == WM_POWERBROADCAST && msg->wParam == PBT_APMPOWERSTATUSCHANGE) {
        qDebug() << "Power changed!!!";
    }

    return false;
}
```

But nothing is printed to the console. Any ideas how to detect it? Thanks.

**Updated: 03.02.2019**

I have found that I need to use the `HID API` to get some values for the `UPS`. Some of the values for `UPS` from the net.

```
 0x00840010 = UPS
 0x00840012 = Battery
 0x00840030 = Voltage
 0x00840040 = ConfigVoltage
 0x0084001a = Input
 0x0084005a = AudibleAlarmControl
 0x00840002 = PresentStatus
 0x00850044 = Charging
 0x00850045 = Discharging
 0x008500d0 = ACPresent
```

**Updated code:**

```
   QString devicePath = "\\\\?\\HID#VID_....";
   HANDLE fileHandle = CreateFileA(devicePath.toStdString().c_str(), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);

   if (fileHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
       std::cout << "Success. Device opened for reading..." << std::endl;
       PHIDP_PREPARSED_DATA preparsedData;
       HIDP_CAPS capabilities;
       HIDD_ATTRIBUTES attributes;
       BOOL hidPreparsedRes = HidD_GetPreparsedData(fileHandle, &preparsedData);

       if (hidPreparsedRes) {
           if (HidD_GetAttributes(fileHandle, &attributes)) {
               std::cout << "Product ID: " << attributes.ProductID << std::endl;
               std::cout << "Size: " << attributes.Size << std::endl;
               std::cout << "Vendor ID: " << attributes.VendorID << std::endl;
               std::cout << "Version number: " << attributes.VersionNumber << std::endl;

              if (HidP_GetCaps(preparsedData, &capabilities) == HIDP_STATUS_SUCCESS) {
                  std::cout << "Caps: " << capabilities.NumberOutputValueCaps << std::endl;
              } else {
                  std::cout << "Failed to return HID capabilities!" << std::endl;
              }
           } else {
              std::cout << "Failed to get HID attributes" << std::endl;
           }

           std::cout << getLastErrorAsString() << std::endl;
       } else {
           std::cout << "Failed to get preparsed data!" << std::endl;
       }

       HidD_FreePreparsedData(preparsedData);
   } else {
       std::cout << "Failed to open device for reading!" << std::endl;
   }

   CloseHandle(fileHandle);
```

So now, it returns:

*Success. Device opened for reading...
Product ID: 20833
Size: 12
Vendor ID: 1637
Version number: 2
Caps: 1*

`HIDP_CAPS` structure has a lot of different values, the question is how to convert them to `UPS` values to check for power changes/`UPS` status? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a battery device shown in the Battery category of Device Manager?

Comment: @BenVoigt

No, I don't have it in `Device Manager`. Also the driver is not available for this `UPS` model. In the `Devices and Printers` it displays as `USB to Serial`.

Comment: @BenVoigt

I added the screenshot:

https://i.ibb.co/bBh3M1Q/2019-01-27-113233.png

Comment: None of the Windows Power Management APIs will work without the driver.  You may open the virtual serial port and talk to it yourself, if you know the protocol.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ok. I will try it. Thank you.